# How do you show a title to only select players using Bukkit?

Tags: java, bukkit

In minecraft it was possible to do this using tags, I was going to try to make the console run the /tag command, but it causes problems with permissions.
I want to show a title or the bossbar only to players the are in a minigame.

Answer (score 0):

you could write your own Plugin for that but I suggest using a API like `BossBarAPI`:
https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/api-bossbarapi-1-7-1-8-1-9-1-10.7504/

they even put an example in the description of their plugin:

```java
//Create a new BossBar
BossBar bossBar = BossBarAPI.addBar(player, // The receiver of the BossBar
      new TextComponent("Hi " + player.getName() + "!"), // Displayed message
      BossBarAPI.Color.BLUE, // Color of the bar
      BossBarAPI.Style.NOTCHED_20, // Bar style
      1.0f, // Progress (0.0 - 1.0)
      20, // Timeout
      2); // Timeout-interval
```